# Tickets created and resolved (or merged) per year

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, aggregate

In a third-party application (RT4) running on MySQL 5.5 I have a series of helpdesk tickets represented as records in a table. Each record has a date/time created, a date/time resolved, and a merge flag (`NULL` or `1`).

```
id int(11) AI PK, Created datetime, Resolved datetime, IsMerged smallint(6)
```

When the ticket is created the created field is populated and the resolved field and merge flag are `NULL`. When the ticket is closed the resolved field is populated. If the ticket is a duplicate the merge flag is set to `1`, and the resolved date is set to `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

I've looked at a number of the offered related answers and of those [mysql: counting number of tickets which are open per day basis](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101249/mysql-counting-number-of-tickets-which-are-open-per-day-basis) seemed the most promising. I feel it's almost what I need but I can't extrapolate from the answers there to my use case.

I can list the number of tickets created per year easily enough -

```
select year(Created) as Created_Yr, count(*) as N_Tickets from rt4.Tickets
group by year(Created)
order by 1
```

A similar query can list the set of non-merged tickets per year -

```
select year(Resolved) as Resolved_Yr, count(*) as N_Tickets from rt4.Tickets
where Resolved is not null
group by year(Resolved)
order by 1
```

However, what I would like is to list the number of tickets resolved or merged, per year.

I can do this year by year like this -

```
select 2016 as Resolved_Yr, count(*) as N_Tickets from rt4.Tickets
where ( Resolved >= '2016-01-01' and Resolved < '2017-01-01' )
or ( Created >= '2016-01-01' and Created < '2017-01-01' and IsMerged = 1 )
```

We have data from years 2012 to 2017 and I'm hoping to avoid having to run a query per year and manually collate the results.

Is there a query that will list the Resolved year (or the Created year if the ticket was merged), for all years present in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT year(Created) AS Created
           FROM rt4.Tickets
       ) AS w

  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT year(Resolved) AS Resolved
                   , count(*) AS resolved_cnt
                FROM rt4.Tickets
               WHERE Resolved IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY year(Resolved) 
            ) AS z
         ON z.Resolved = w.Created

  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT year(Created) AS Created
                   , count(*) AS merged_cnt
                FROM rt4.Tickets
               WHERE Merged IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY year(Created) 
            ) AS q
         ON q.Created = w.Created
;
```

Sure you have to remember that functional restrictions like `year()` in the `WHERE`, `JOIN...ON` or `GROUP BY` clauses cannot be speeded up by indexes and can be VERY slow.

I hope that query wouldn't be runned on the regular basis.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you. Just FTR I've used `SELECT w.Created, w.created_cnt, z.resolved_cnt + ifnull(q.merged_cnt,0) as N_Resolved_Merged`, and changed the `SELECT DISTINCT ...` to a `SELECT year(Created), count(*) ... GROUP BY`.